# Python Email via MS Exchange: Message Submission Rate Limit

Tags: python, email, exchange-server

I have written a Python script that iterates through rows of an Excel file and, for each row:

1. Gets an e-mail address, name, and name of attachment file to use
2. Composes an e-mail
3. Sends out the e-mail

I'm not sure if it's accurate to call this mass-emailing or if it is a candidate for being black-listed because it is sending out individualized e-mails. With a message submission rate of 5/minute, I want to throttle it (or have the limit increased to 100).

So my question is: Is the sort of scenario, assuming the limit is increased to 100, prone to black-listing?

Answer (score 0):

**It depends on how well you know the people you're mailing.**

If you know them pretty well, it should be fine. If they're total strangers, the recipients might think it's spam and start blocking you.

**I could help more if you told me how well you know the recipients.**

Comment: The recipients are individuals who have applied for a job or are about to start working with our organization. They would usually receive the exact same e-mails, only composed and sent manually.

Answer (score 0):

Its not easy to answer your question as it depends hardly on the remote email environment used here and what you understand with individualized emails (only a different "Hello Mr. ZZ" or "Dear Ms. YY" isn´t really an individualized email these days). To give you three possible examples:

*Situation 1:*
All users are on the same email environment (e.g. Exchange Online / Office 365). Then the remote mail server might see here +100 similar emails and might mark them as spam. If all +100 users are on +100 different email servers that might be different however the following might be possible:

*Situation 2:*
One user think that this email is spam and report that as spam. Depending on the AntiSpam engine used here a hash value from that email might be created and other email server using the same AntiSpam engine might therefore detect your email as spam as well.

*Situation 3:*
The users are on different email environments but in front of them is an AntiSpam cloud solution. This solution will then see +100 similar emails from one eMail environment and might therefore clarify that as SPAM.

*Offtopic: You might consider using services like from MailChimp which use different email servers to spread out a similar email. This might help to prevent such issues as the mass emails aren´t send from only one server. On top of that you do not risk your own email server from being blacklisted which might have a very bad business impact on your company.*